# Unable to browse to certain sites

Tags: networking, virtualization, ssl, xen

I have a few guests on a XenServer host, and some sites ( both SSL and non SSL ) cannot be accessed by the XenHost and the Guests. Other machines on the same network can access these sites just fine, and except for these specific sites, the XenServer and its guests can access other sites just fine.

- I checked DNS, the guests and the host are able to resolve the hostname
- I connected to the non ssl site via telnet, it hangs after sending the host header
- I tried to connect to the ssl site via openssl s_client and it hangs at SSL_Connect unknown state. There is another SSL site in the same network as the ssl site that hangs, and it works fine.
- Machines which are not on this XenServer , but on the same network access all sites just fine.

The XenServer has 2 connections ( the outbound interface that the guests use is 1Gbps with the default 1500MTU ), the other interface is the bonded network connection to a NAS.

The output of openssl s_client is as follows:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
    TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 013b], ClientHello
    01 00 01 37 03 03 53 c5 58 1b 88 09 72 5e 2a b6
    55 3c 38 1c 6a 5f 1f c1 7b 2e 4a 86 9c f3 24 c7
    9e 9a 66 3b ee f3 00 00 9e c0 30 c0 2c c0 28 c0
    24 c0 14 c0 0a c0 22 c0 21 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b 00
    6a 00 39 00 38 00 88 00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a c0
    26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d 00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 12 c0
    08 c0 1c c0 1b 00 16 00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a c0
    2f c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13 c0 09 c0 1f c0 1e 00
    a2 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 33 00 32 00 9a 00 99 00
    45 00 44 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00
    9c 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0
    02 00 05 00 04 00 15 00 12 00 09 00 14 00 11 00
    08 00 06 00 03 00 ff 02 01 00 00 6f 00 0b 00 04
    03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 34 00 32 00 0e 00 0d 00 19
    00 0b 00 0c 00 18 00 09 00 0a 00 16 00 17 00 08
    00 06 00 07 00 14 00 15 00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13
    00 01 00 02 00 03 00 0f 00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00
    00 0d 00 22 00 20 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02
    05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01
    02 02 02 03 01 01 00 0f 00 01 01
SSL_connect:unknown state
```